# Are doxygen style documentation comments prohibitive in C#?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, documentation, intellisense, doxygen

I have a project that I documented(in source code) basically as an after thought. It wasn't all that big of a project and only I use it(that I know of) so it wasn't a big deal. I did it using Doxygen because I wanted all of my documentation to be capable of being exported into HTML. My problem is I used Doxygen style comments, instead of the standard XML style comments(which I dislike, but anyway).

Now I'm looking at trying to sell this code and before I try that I want to make sure it's of good quality. The problem I'm seeing with Doxygen style comments is that they don't get intellisense support. Other than that, are non-XML comments prohibitive in C#? Is there any options to set in Visual Studio to get Intellisense support?

Answer (score 1):

If you want intellisense, then you have to use the XML comments. The Visual C# compiler does not recognize or understand Doxygen.

If you want to use the XML comments to generate HTML documentation, use [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) -- that's what it's for.

Comment: But Sandcastle is so ugly :/. But Doxygen supports XML comments apparently, so I'll just have to convert all of my source documentation I suppose

Comment: Hmm... I think Doxygen is ugly. Are you sure you set it up right? (It comes with several themes and such out of the box) Different strokes for different folks I guess.

Comment: I've seen multiple examples, including Microsoft's own source documentation and I find it's structure very dense, yet difficult to find whatever I need... and yes, ugly too

Comment: Note that you need a space between the /// and the opening < of XML comments to avoid Doxygen parsing them as an inline comment ///< specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my documentation addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/).

It can read Doxygen comments and convert them into the XML Documentation format. It'll process entire scope blocks in a single pass, so can be used to quickly convert legacy documentation to a different format.

It's also very configurable, so you can tweak the output to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: I didn't have a lot of code to convert, so I just spend an hour or two and did it all at once. If I was working on a larger project I could definitely see this as useful